# LazyAdapter duplicates images

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-asynctask, android-lazyadapter

I have a Lazy adapter that add the title, subtitle, and picture to a ListView. Lately I have been noticing in my ListView that my images are being duplicated.

Here is where I add my array to the adapter

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {                   
    LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(Services.this,menuItems);     
    serviceList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is where I call the async method to add my image (its a url thats why it is in a async method)

```
vi.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
title.setText(items.get("title")); // Set Title
listData.setText(items.get("htmlcontent")); // Set content          
thumb_image.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.serviceborder);//Adds border
new setLogoImage(thumb_image).execute(); // Async Method call
```

And here is where I set my bitmap image

```
private class setLogoImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView imv;            

        public setLogoImage(ImageView imv) {
             this.imv = imv;                 
        }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {               
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(items.get("thumburl")).getContent());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {           
        imv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 50, 50, false));
    }
}
```

The `items` variable is a HashMap that stores my info. I get the position of the data given to the adapter and assign it to the items HashMap. Like so:

```
items = new HashMap<String, String>();
items = data.get(position);
```

This happens randomly, it seems, and it gets annoying to see the wrong picture there about 30% of the time, especially when I'm trying to debug.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Here is an image to see what is happening
[image]

Comment: If you want to do this in a more friendly way, you can use the [`UrlImageViewHelper` project by koush.](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have something that happens randomly, and you have any kind of a thread, you should think two works, Race Condition. Basically, your AsyncTasks are all loading the same image. They should be passed in the value to load. I noticed you aren't doing anything with params. I'm not sure exactly what you should do, but the problem is somewhere in your AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {               
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(items.get("thumburl")).getContent());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {             
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

You should probably pass in the URL (Or the string it represents). In this example, I pass in the URL, but feel free to change it around how you want. The key thing is, you should pass a representation of the image location into the function, rather than try to figure out what image to use when you are in the function.

```
new setLogoImage(new Url(items.get("thumburl"))).execute(); // Async Method call


@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Url... input) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {               
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)input[0]).getContent());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {             
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: You can pass the string, but the key thing is to pass what you want to use, don't try to get it inside of the AsyncTask.

Comment: Well With your code I get a "Cannot cast from URL to InputStream". Any ideas?

Comment: Alternatively, you could just pass `items.get("thumburl")`, and do the same conversion you originally are doing.

Comment: Ya thats what I ended up doing. Thanks for the help